# Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process - FileUpload button

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, azure

I did browse through all the other answers but still cannot figure out what is wrong. 
I am trying out a simple `fileUpload` in an Azure project.

It may be that I am not closing my filestream. 
The following is my code:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "zip/rar/tar")
            {
                string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + fileName);
                Label2.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully !";
            }
            else
            {
                Label2.Text = "File type not allowed.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Text = "Error in File Upload. Please upload a zip/tar/rar file containing your text files.";
        }           
    }
}
```

How should I close the file stream ?

Thanks
Supraja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message says everything. The file you are trying to save as is used by "something" and therefore it's locked. Try changing the filename and it should work with no error, at least once. RD to the server if you can, and try to delete the file manually and it will tell what program is using that file. SaveAs method should not require disposal, but if there's a Close() method, call that one. Else if there is Dispose() method, call that one, after SaveAs(), and it should work well.

Comment: if it's Azure, you should use persistent storage like the blob storage to save files to, otherwise they'll be lost when you cycle your instance. Also it's not wise to save files into your applications root, as you could overwrite an application file or allow malicious content to be added to your app.

Comment: Yeah, nice comment from a security-perspective. Didn't notice it was uploading to the root directory of the app.

Comment: @Simon: I am trying to write an Azure app. The first step of which is to upload zip/tar/rar files and then distribute the files inside among thee workers.

Comment: If you don't need to keep the files then no problem. You should still use a temp folder that is not web accessible. You could use System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName to ensure you have a unique name on disk or use a guid for the filename.